# Partition a collection into "k" close-to-equal pieces (Scala, but language agnostic)

Tags: algorithm, scala, slice

Defined before this block of code:

- `dataset` can be a `Vector` or `List`
- `numberOfSlices` is an `Int` denoting how many "times" to slice dataset

I want to split the dataset into `numberOfSlices` slices, distributed as evenly as possible. By "split" I guess I mean "partition" (intersection of all should be empty, union of all should be the original) to use the set theory term, though this is not necessarily a set, just an arbitrary collection.

e.g.

```
dataset = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
numberOfSlices = 3
slices == ListBuffer(Vector(1, 2), Vector(3, 4), Vector(5, 6, 7))
```

Is there a better way to do it than what I have below? (which I'm not even sure is optimal...)
Or perhaps this is not an algorithmically feasible endeavor, in which case any known good heuristics?

```
val slices = new ListBuffer[Vector[Int]]
val stepSize = dataset.length / numberOfSlices
var currentStep = 0
var looper = 0
while (looper != numberOfSlices) {
  if (looper != numberOfSlices - 1) {
    slices += dataset.slice(currentStep, currentStep + stepSize)
    currentStep += stepSize
  } else {
    slices += dataset.slice(currentStep, dataset.length)
  }
  looper += 1
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret "distributed as evenly as possible". Going by your code, `Seq:grouped(Int)` already does what you want, except that it never goes above the slice size.

Comment: It seems `grouped` will divided it into groups of "x" whereas I want to divide a collection into "x" groups. I tried it in the reply, `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).grouped(2).toList` gives `List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5))` whereas I want something like `List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 5))`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the behavior of `xs.grouped(xs.size / n)` doesn't work for you, it's pretty easy to define exactly what you want. The quotient is the size of the smaller pieces, and the remainder is the number of the bigger pieces:

```
def cut[A](xs: Seq[A], n: Int) = {
  val (quot, rem) = (xs.size / n, xs.size % n)
  val (smaller, bigger) = xs.splitAt(xs.size - rem * (quot + 1))
  smaller.grouped(quot) ++ bigger.grouped(quot + 1)
}
```

Comment: This is good but unfortunately stretches the stated requirement of 'distributed as evenly as possible', as all the 'big' segments come last - for instance, `cut(1 to 15, 10).toList.map(_.size)` yields 5 one-element segements followed by 5 two-element segments.

Answer (score 8):

The typical "optimal" partition calculates an exact fractional length after cutting and then rounds to find the actual number to take:

```
def cut[A](xs: Seq[A], n: Int):Vector[Seq[A]] = {
  val m = xs.length
  val targets = (0 to n).map{x => math.round((x.toDouble*m)/n).toInt}
  def snip(xs: Seq[A], ns: Seq[Int], got: Vector[Seq[A]]): Vector[Seq[A]] = {
    if (ns.length<2) got
    else {
      val (i,j) = (ns.head, ns.tail.head)
      snip(xs.drop(j-i), ns.tail, got :+ xs.take(j-i))
    }
  }
  snip(xs, targets, Vector.empty)
}
```

This way your longer and shorter blocks will be interspersed, which is often more desirable for evenness:

```
scala> cut(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),4)
res5: Vector[Seq[Int]] = 
  Vector(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(9, 10))
```

You can even cut more times than you have elements:

```
scala> cut(List(1,2,3),5)
res6: Vector[Seq[Int]] = 
  Vector(List(1), List(), List(2), List(), List(3))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner that does the job for me, using the familiar Scala trick of a recursive function that returns a `Stream`. Notice the use of `(x+k/2)/k` to round the chunk sizes, intercalating the smaller and larger chunks in the final list, all with sizes with at most one element of difference. If you round up instead, with `(x+k-1)/k`, you move the smaller blocks to the end, and `x/k` moves them to the beginning.

```
def k_folds(k: Int, vv: Seq[Int]): Stream[Seq[Int]] =
    if (k > 1)
        vv.take((vv.size+k/2)/k) +: k_folds(k-1, vv.drop((vv.size+k/2)/k))
    else
        Stream(vv)
```

Demo:

```
scala> val indices = scala.util.Random.shuffle(1 to 39)

scala> for (ff <- k_folds(7, indices)) println(ff)
Vector(29, 8, 24, 14, 22, 2)
Vector(28, 36, 27, 7, 25, 4)
Vector(6, 26, 17, 13, 23)
Vector(3, 35, 34, 9, 37, 32)
Vector(33, 20, 31, 11, 16)
Vector(19, 30, 21, 39, 5, 15)
Vector(1, 38, 18, 10, 12)

scala> for (ff <- k_folds(7, indices)) println(ff.size)
6
6
5
6
5
6
5

scala> for (ff <- indices.grouped((indices.size+7-1)/7)) println(ff)
Vector(29, 8, 24, 14, 22, 2)
Vector(28, 36, 27, 7, 25, 4)
Vector(6, 26, 17, 13, 23, 3)
Vector(35, 34, 9, 37, 32, 33)
Vector(20, 31, 11, 16, 19, 30)
Vector(21, 39, 5, 15, 1, 38)
Vector(18, 10, 12)

scala> for (ff <- indices.grouped((indices.size+7-1)/7)) println(ff.size)
6
6
6
6
6
6
3
```

Notice how `grouped` does not try to even out the size of all the sub-lists.

Comment: @Vasily802 I don't know why `#::` might not have worked, but I have replaced it and also improved the code a bit, and fixed the demo. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on the problem:

```
  def partition[T](items: Seq[T], partitionsCount: Int): List[Seq[T]] = {
    val minPartitionSize = items.size / partitionsCount
    val extraItemsCount = items.size % partitionsCount

    def loop(unpartitioned: Seq[T], acc: List[Seq[T]], extra: Int): List[Seq[T]] =
      if (unpartitioned.nonEmpty) {
        val (splitIndex, newExtra) = if (extra > 0) (minPartitionSize + 1, extra - 1) else (minPartitionSize, extra)
        val (newPartition, remaining) = unpartitioned.splitAt(splitIndex)
        loop(remaining, newPartition :: acc, newExtra)
      } else acc

    loop(items, List.empty, extraItemsCount).reverse
  }
```

It's more verbose than some of the other solutions but hopefully more clear as well. **reverse** is only necessary if you want the order to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

As Kaito mentions `grouped` is exactly what you are looking for. But if you just want to know how to implement such a method, there are many ways ;-). You could for example do it like this:

```
def grouped[A](xs: List[A], size: Int) = {
  def grouped[A](xs: List[A], size: Int, result: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
    if(xs.isEmpty) {
      result
    } else {
      val (slice, rest) = xs.splitAt(size)
      grouped(rest, size, result :+ slice)
    }
  }
  grouped(xs, size, Nil)
}
```

Comment: `grouped` does not make the sizes as even as possible, the last sub-list might be much smaller than the others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it this way: Given `n` elements and `m` partitions (n>m), either n mod m == 0 in which case, each partition will have n/m elements, or  n mod m = y, in which case you'll have  each partition with `n/m` elements and you have to distribute `y` over some `m`.

You'll have `y` slots with `n/m+1` elements and (m-y) slots with n/m. How you distribute them is your choice.