# Splitting a Scala Range into evenly-sized contiguous sub-Ranges

Tags: scala, range

If I have a Range, how can I split it into a sequence of contiguous sub-ranges, where the number of sub-ranges (buckets) is specified? Empty buckets should be omitted if there are not enough items.

For example:

```
splitRange(1 to 6, 3) == Seq(Range(1,2), Range(3,4), Range(5,6))
splitRange(1 to 2, 3) == Seq(Range(1), Range(2))
```

Some additional constraints, that rule out some of the solutions I've seen:

1. Roughly even bucket size - the bucket size should vary by 1, at most
2. The length of the input range may sometimes be very large, so the ranges should not be materialized into sequences (e.g. can't use `grouped`)
3. This also implies that we don't allocate numbers to buckets in round-robin fashion, because then numbers in each bucket wouldn't be contiguous and so wouldn't form a Range
4. Ideally, the sub-ranges would be produced in order, i.e (1,2)(3,4), not (3,4)(1,2)

A colleague found a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/asieira/fadcf6799242d657213abafc23884d6f):

```
def splitRange(r: Range, chunks: Int): Seq[Range] = {
  if (r.step != 1) 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range must have step size equal to 1")

  val nchunks = scala.math.max(chunks, 1)
  val chunkSize = scala.math.max(r.length / nchunks, 1)
  val starts = r.by(chunkSize).take(nchunks)
  val ends = starts.map(_ - 1).drop(1) :+ r.end
  starts.zip(ends).map(x => x._1 to x._2)
}
```

but this can produce very uneven bucket sizes when N is small, e.g:

```
splitRange(1 to 14, 5)                          
//> Vector(Range(1, 2), Range(3, 4), Range(5, 6),
//|        Range(7, 8), Range(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456107/partition-a-collection-into-k-close-to-equal-pieces-scala-but-language-agnos

Comment: Thanks! That question is slightly different, but I have adapted one of the solutions into my answer below (crediting the original author).

Answer (score 5):

**Floating-point approaches**

One way is to generate a fractional (floating-point) offset for each bucket, then convert these to integer Ranges, by zipping. Empty Ranges also need filtering out using `collect`.

```
def splitRange(r: Range, chunks: Int): Seq[Range] = {
  require(r.step == 1, "Range must have step size equal to 1")
  require(chunks >= 1, "Must ask for at least 1 chunk")

  val m = r.length.toDouble
  val chunkSize = m / chunks
  val bins = (0 to chunks).map { x => math.round((x.toDouble * m) / chunks).toInt }
  val pairs = bins zip (bins.tail)
  pairs.collect { case (a, b) if b > a => a to b }
}
```

(The first version of this solution had a rounding problem such that it could not handle `Int.MaxValue` - this has now been fixed based on Rex Kerr's recursive floating-point solution below)

Another floating-point approach is to recurse down the range, taking the head off the range each time, so we cannot miss any elements. This version can handle `Int.MaxValue` correctly.

```
def splitRange(r: Range, chunks: Int): Seq[Range] = {
  require(r.step == 1, "Range must have step size equal to 1")
  require(chunks >= 1, "Must ask for at least 1 chunk")

  val chunkSize = r.length.toDouble / chunks

  def go(i: Int, r: Range, delta: Double, acc: List[Range]): List[Range] = {  
    if (i == chunks) r :: acc 
      // ensures the last chunk has all remaining values, even if error accumulates
    else {
      val s = delta + chunkSize
      val (chunk, rest) = r.splitAt(s.toInt)
      go(i + 1, rest, s - s.toInt, if (chunk.length > 0) chunk :: acc else acc)
    }
  }

  go(1, r, 0.0D, Nil).reverse
}
```

One can also recurse to generate the (start,end) pairs, rather than zipping them. This is adapted from Rex Kerr's [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11458240/699224)

```
def splitRange(r: Range, chunks: Int): Seq[Range] = {
  require(r.step == 1, "Range must have step size equal to 1")
  require(chunks >= 1, "Must ask for at least 1 chunk")

  val m = r.length
  val bins = (0 to chunks).map { x => math.round((x.toDouble * m) / chunks).toInt }
  def snip(r: Range, ns: Seq[Int], got: Vector[Range]): Vector[Range] = {
    if (ns.length < 2) got
    else {
      val (i, j) = (ns.head, ns.tail.head)
      snip(r.drop(j - i), ns.tail, got :+ r.take(j - i))
    }
  }
 snip(r, bins, Vector.empty).filter(_.length > 0)
}
```

**Integer approach**

Finally, I realized that this can be done with purely integer arithmetic by adapting [Bresenham's line-drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm), which solves a basically equivalent problem - how to allocate the x-pixels evenly across the y rows, using only integer operations!

I initially translated the pseudo-code into an imperative solution using `var` and `ArrayBuffer`, then converted it into a tail-recursive solution:

```
def splitRange(r: Range, chunks: Int): List[Range] = {
  require(r.step == 1, "Range must have step size equal to 1")
  require(chunks >= 1, "Must ask for at least 1 chunk")

  val dy = r.length
  val dx = chunks

  @tailrec
  def go(y0:Int, y:Int, d:Int, ch:Int, acc: List[Range]):List[Range] = {
    if (ch == 0) acc
    else {
      if (d > 0) go(y0, y-1, d-dx, ch, acc)
      else go(y-1, y, d+dy, ch-1, if (y > y0) acc 
                                  else (y to y0) :: acc)
    }
  }

  go(r.end, r.end, dy - dx, chunks, Nil)
}
```

Please see the Wikipedia link for a full explanation, but essentially the algorithm zig-zags up the slope of a line, alternatively adding the y-range `dy` and subtracting the x-range `dx`. If these don't divide exactly, then an error accumulates until it divides exactly, leading to an extra pixel in some sub-ranges.

```
splitRange(3 to 15, 5)                         
//> List(Range(3, 4), Range(5, 6, 7), Range(8, 9), 
//|      Range(10, 11, 12), Range(13, 14, 15))
```